# Add a css class to the active link then remove it when becomes inactive

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I know this question might not fit here but I am afraid that I am doing something wrong related to Drupal since it is my first time with JS code and its implementation into Drupal core.

I have placed a block available on all of my pages made with views and is working as the main menu for all users.

This view block consists of 3 **Custom Text** fields having the same class name: **menu-item** as below:

- **Custom Text fields #1:** `<a class="menu-item home-item" href="/link-1">Home</a>`
- **Custom Text fields #2:** `<a class="menu-item services-item" href="/link-2">Services</a>`
- **Custom Text fields #3:** `<a class="menu-item contact-item" href="/link-3">Contact</a>`

I want to add the class name **active-page** to a link once a user clicked on a it then remove it once the user click on another link in that block.

I am using a subtheme of Bartik theme and so far:

**general_css.css** file:

```
.active-page {
background-color: blue;
}
```

**THEME_NAME.libraries.yml** file:

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/general_css.css: {}
global-scripts:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/general_js.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

**THEME_NAME.info.yml** file:

```
libraries:
  - 'THEME_NAME/global-styling'
  - 'THEME_NAME/global-scripts'
```

**js/general_js.js** file:

```
(function ($, window, Drupal) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu-item").on('click', function (e) {
      $(this).addClass("active-page") // Add active-page class to the clicked link.
        .siblings() // Select clicked link brothers.
        .removeClass("active-page"); // Remove active-page class if exist from clicked link brothers.
    })
  });
})(jQuery, window, Drupal);
```

Using Chrome browser and while inspecting the element, I have clicked on a link from the block and during the loading of the page, the **active-page** class has been successfully added to the clicked link; However the **active-page** class has disappeared directly after the loading of the page has finished.

Any help on what is missing here ?

Thank you,

Comment: Menu links receive an active class if the item path is in the active trail.

Comment: @Kevin, for specific needs, I am not using a menu entity but a view block that acts like a menu... and the **active** class is not added to the block item when the item path is in the active trail which is not the case when inspecting the **Admin** menu (the built-in top fixed black menu)

Answer (score 1):

"menu-item" is a global class which can be used with several links on your Drupal site, so you have to be more specific with your css selectors (for example use your block ID and then the selector will be "#yourBlockId .menu-item".

Also I invite you to use jQuery library it will help you to simply implement your JS solution by using jQuery methods ([addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/#addClass-className), [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#removeClass-className), [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/),...).

First add jQuery as a dependency of your global-scripts library:
**THEME_NAME.libraries.yml** file

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/general_css.css: {}
global-scripts:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/general_js.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

**js/general_js.js** file:

```
(function ($, window, Drupal) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourBlockID .menu-item').on('click', function (e) {
      $(this).addClass('active-page') // Add active-page class to the clicked link.
        .siblings() // Select clicked link brothers.
        .removeClass('active-page'); // Remove active-page class if exist from clicked link brothers.
    })
  });
})(jQuery, window, Drupal);
```

Comment: Thank you for  your reply, I have followed your instructions and cleared all caches but still when I click on a link from that block, nothing is happening even the class name is not added to the link ! I have updated my question to become more clear.

Comment: your code is working now but using Chrome browser and while inspecting the element, I have clicked on a link from the block and during the loading of the page, the `active-page` class has been successfully added to the clicked link; However the `active-page` class has disappeared directly after the loading of the page has finished. any idea on how to fix this ?